# Cannot read external hard disk folders created in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, external-hdd

I am experiencing a problem. I tried to plug in my external hard disk on Ubuntu. I copied in to it some folders (created on Ubuntu) with files in them.

Then, I plugged it on Windows and I wasn't able to copy or modify any of the copies folders or sub-folders. I could access my files (and modify them), but I couldn't modify or copy any of the folders or sub-folders.

I tried formatting my computer's and the external hard disk, that did not make a difference.

What should I do?

wimvds --> Thanks for your answer, first of all :) Yes! I did. I always use "Unmount" on linux as well as on windows...

Misery --> No errors are promoted during the copy process. What do you mean by saying "attributions"?? :/

Comment: Did you by any chance just unplug your HDD? If so you should mount it again in Linux and click the Unmount icon (eject button icon) next to the external HDD before unplugging the device.

Comment: Ubuntu recognizes NTFS partitions without any problem so it should work normally. Does it prompt any error while copying folders from Your HDD to Windows?

Did You try to right-click on the folders and see what attributes they have?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said this is file permissions.

Use Microsoft's "xcacls" (a downloadable tool by Microsoft for Windows sysadmins) because I believe it's a Windows issue. I used to see this on Windows Servers sometimes when the ACL (Access Control List) is borked.

Take ownership of everything (important) and then assign 'full control' access level.

You shouldn't have to do it each time.

Answer (score 0):

What types of files are you trying to access from the windows machine? Have you tried copying those files using the windows cmd window? Try using chmod -r 777  on the folder in the hard drive. Also, have you tried zipping the folder on Ubuntu, then copying that file over to the external HDD? Also, have you done anything to the external HDD since you bought it? Maybe it has some type of copy protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This most likely was your problem. When the USB was created it was made to only be compatible with Ubuntu (ext 2, ext 4, or encrypted). What you need to to to fix this problem is format the USB as 'FAT' compatible with all systems. This should solve you problem.   I had this very dame problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the NTFS read-only attribute has been set.  Check in Windows that the files do not have the read-only attribute set.  I've never seen this happen with an NTFS filesystem used under Ubuntu.

If it's ext2 or ext4, what ext driver have you installed to access the ext partition?

Answer (score -1):

The file you copied might be encrypted or it could be [what @Shannon_VanWagner posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/127471/22949)...