# How can I pause and download again from ubuntu software center

Tags: 12.04

I'm updating my ubuntu 12.04lts now. But my laptop battery is very low now so is it possible that now i can pause my download in the software center and start it again from the same position.How can I do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

this question has been answered here :

[How can I pause/resume an apt-get update process in a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35394/how-can-i-pause-resume-an-apt-get-update-process-in-a-terminal)

you can't do this with the gui.

if you need to restart (and i bet you need), there is no way to do it.