# Is an interrupted internet connection during software updates dangerous?

Tags: networking, apt, updates, update-manager

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04. Where I live, the internet connection often suddenly breaks!

I missed the connection once while upgrading the system release which finally has lead to errors requiring a reinstall. I am afraid that my system will be damaged, or that I have to deal with errors after interrupted normal software updates as well.

What are the possible dangers of losing the internet connection during software updates, and what do you suggest about that?

Comment: Are you talking about normal software updates or about a release version upgrade (e.g. from 15.04 to 15.10)?

Comment: Normal software updates. In fact, previously I missed the connection during upgrading and it caused big damages that enforced me to reinstall the system. because of that I am worry.

Answer (score 10):

During normal software updates, I think a connection reset is not dangerous. It may lead to (sometimes persisting until you fix it) error messages of `apt`, but nothing that should really damage the system.

---

When you run `sudo apt-get update` or let the GUI Software Updater do this manually or automatically as background task, it will fetch the updated package lists.

If the connection resets, you get an error that it failed to download a list.
You can (or must) simply repeat the process later when the connection is restored and everything will work again.

---

When you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or let the GUI Software Updater update installed packages, the process consists of roughly 2 steps:

- It will as first step download all new binary packages.

  If the connection breaks during this step, there will be an error and it will abort. No package has been changed yet, no damage was done.
  You can simply repeat the upgrade later (recommended, as you should always keep your packages up to date) or not.
- In the second step, it will first unpack each downloaded package over the currently installed one and then reconfigure it, if necessary.

  For both operations, *usually no internet connection is required*, because the binary package file containing all the stuff is already present on your disk. A connection loss will not affect anything.

  **But** some special packages do not contain the real package, but just a downloader/installer application which automatically gets invoked and performs the real installation. (Updates are the same as reinstalling a package with a different version on Linux systems) Popular examples are the Microsoft Fonts `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` or the Adobe Flash player `flashplugin-installer`, basically most or all packages containing "`-installer`" in their name.
  If your connection breaks during the second step updating/installing one of those packages, while the install script is downloading the real package data, this script will fail and the installer package will stay in an unconfigured state. You usually have to purge and reinstall it if that happens.

Comment: I don't think `purge` would be needed. Last time the network connection failed on me while updating flash this command was sufficient to get it working again for me: `apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

Comment: The real danger, in most cases, is not losing the connection.  It's losing power or otherwise crashing while packages are being installed or upgraded.  Recovering from that is a real pain (most APT tools will say "We can't do anything with that package, it's broken!" and you end up fiddling with dpkg by hand).

Answer (score 3):

The APT package management tool performs upgrades in the following way:

1. Download all packages that are to be upgraded
2. Install upgrades once all downloads succeeded

So should your internet connection drop while the upgrades are being downloaded, you'll receive a timeout exception and the upgrade process will be cancelled. So there won't be any harm to your system. If you experience this problem a lot, and are therefore unable to install updates, you can try upgrading single packages manually using

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Here you can insert the package names listed when executing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Notice that still multiple packages may need to be upgraded, if they depend on each other. Also, you may want to look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35394/how-can-i-pause-resume-an-apt-get-update-process-in-a-terminal) related question.