# Can you cancel an upgrade in progress? Upgrade from terminal hangs at same point, every time. Even on a fresh reinstall

Tags: command-line, upgrade

Picture of screen:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/HkKeBTEQr57G53Kq6

I'm really not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can cancel upgrade that is in running. use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to do completely stop the upgrade. But don't try unless you have no other choice because the system might become unstable or unusable.

You can also do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> that can pause the upgrade and you can resume with `fg`.

upgrading/updating is an atomic operation. Either it completes, or it doesn't. If the update breaks/stops then it rollbacks to the last point before update began. Because the headers (files that contain data of packages, and where to fetch them from). The packages however, begin downloading from the point that your connection broke off. But, still there's chances of harming the system.
[Referred this](https://askubuntu.com/a/35402/867994)

Comment: It's completely frozen, anyways. No Reisub no f...nothing works. Manual power cycle, now I've  got a grub prompt. :(

Comment: Really sorry to hear that @SirTwis7

Comment: I was able to follow a guide on booting from grub. Everything is fine. I've read the info that link took me to. Good stuff! Thank you so much, @Adil Saju, I'd have never known...